# Show that the decryption transformation for the El Gamal cryptosystem works.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Want to show that, if $P$ is the original plaintext block and $(\gamma^a)'$ is the inverse of $\gamma^a$ modulo $p$, then
$$(\gamma^a)'\delta \equiv P \pmod p$$

So, we have:

- $\gamma = \alpha^k \pmod p$
- $\delta = P(\alpha^a)^k mod p$
- $C = (\gamma, \delta)$

Plugging the values above to $(\gamma^a)'\delta$
$$(\gamma^a)'\delta = ((\alpha^k)^a)' P(\alpha^a)^k \equiv P \pmod p$$
$$((\alpha^k)^a)' P(\alpha^a)^k \equiv ((\alpha^k)^a)' (\alpha^a)^k  \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

Not sure if I'm doing this correctly...

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We want to show that if $(\gamma^a)'$ is the inverse of $\gamma^a$ modulo $p$, then
$(\gamma^a)'\delta \equiv P \pmod p$.

We have:

- $\gamma = \alpha^k \pmod p$
- $\delta = P(\alpha^a)^k \pmod p$
- $C = (\gamma, \delta)$

So, we need to find: $(\gamma^a)'\delta$

Plug in the above values and what do end up with?

$$(\gamma^a)'\delta = ((\alpha^k)^a)' P(\alpha^a)^k \equiv \alpha^{-ak} \cdot \alpha^{ak} P \equiv P \pmod p $$

What allows me to swap and cancel those values?

Comment: ...nice job here, too!

Comment: Thanks for responding, but still unsure about how to proceed.  I've update the post with what you've suggested but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: @Amzoti Ok, so can you divide both sides by $\alpha^{-ak}$?.  If so, it seems like I end up with $1 \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: @icanc: Huh? the RHS is our final result and is P. Why are you dividing anything from the left of that? Maybe just a slip up? Regards